# How to remove an array in dimensional associative array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the json array like this

`var fruitList = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"ID":31, "fruit": "apple", "number":3}, {"ID":32, "fruit": "orange", "number":23}, {"ID":34, "fruit": "grape", "number":12}, {"ID":35, "fruit": "banana", "number":42}]');`

I want remove two array: **if "ID" = 32**, and **if "number" = 42**
the following result is I want, how to get the indexOf ID is 32?

`[{"ID":31, "fruit": "apple", "number":3}, {"ID":34, "fruit": "grape", "number":12}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get new filtered array:

```js
var fruitList = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"ID":31, "fruit": "apple", "number":3}, {"ID":32, "fruit": "orange", "number":23}, {"ID":34, "fruit": "grape", "number":12}, {"ID":35, "fruit": "banana", "number":42}]');

let result = fruitList.filter(x => x.ID !== 32 && x.number !== 42);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```